Windows contextual menu activation
I have an application I wrote to Open , Create and Edit Windows *.ico files. I made a Contextual menu item to Open the icon using the "%1" method in the registry. The Application opens but the icon does not populate the edit field.
My def is called open_icon to open files in my editor. What do I need to add to my script to allow the %1 variable to be used as the input to my application once it is converted to an EXE file?
